# Is the normalization of a blowup of a LC variety again LC ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If I blow up a subvariety Z in a log canonical variety X and then normalize, is the resulting variety X' log canonical?

I reason as follows.  Let Y-->X' be a strong resolution of singularities.  If an exceptional divisor appears with coefficient less than -1, it would have to cancel by an exceptional divisor of X'-->X because X is LC and Y-->X'-->X is a resolution of singularities.  But no such divisor can exist because the generic points of exceptional divisors in X'-->X are smooth, hence in the isomorphism locus.

Comment: It's about Frobenius split rather than log canonical varieties, but I think that "Frobenius splitting and blow-ups" will tell you that you need stronger conditions. http://www.math.neu.edu/~lakshmibai/frob.ps

Comment: There are two issues to worry about: first you need to show that $K_{X'}$ is $\mathbb Q$ Cartier (this is often true, eg. if the exceptional divisor is irreducible). At any rate, you can always write $f^*K_X=K_{X'}+E'$ where $(X',E')$ is sub-log canonical (meaning that $E'$ may not be effective). However we then have the second issue: Since $E'$ is not effective, it is not clear that $(X',E')$ sub log canonical implies that $X'$ is log canonical (even if $K_{X'}$ is $\mathbb Q$-Cartier). AK's link seems to be broken, so I couldn't see if this is the issue he is pointing out.

Comment: Oops! I found a way around: http://mathserver.neu.edu/~lakshmibai/frob.ps